# How to create a float[] of NaNs?

Tags: java, arrays

Can I create a `float[]` consisting of three `Float.NaN` in a short way? I'm passing it as a method argument, so I'd like the expression to be brief.

Comment: Use a for loop, or Arrays.fill()

Comment: someFunction({Float.NaN,Float.NaN,Float.NaN});

Comment: @Ziul That won't compile.

Comment: oh, sorry, let me fix it

Answer (score 12):

You could use [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28float%5B%5D,%20float%29):

```
float[] nans = new float[3];
Arrays.fill(nans, Float.NaN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method that abstracts and hides the behavior of building the array, and pass it as an argument to your function in a way that is very clean and easy to read:

```
public static float[] nanFloatArr(int len) {
  float[] arr = new float[len];
  Arrays.fill(arr, Float.NaN);
  return arr;
}
```

Then you can call it concisely: `yourMethod( nanFloatArr(3) );`

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following

```
float[] nans = {Float.NaN ,Float.NaN,Float.NaN};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
someFunction( new float[]{Float.NaN,Float.NaN,Float.NaN} );
```